# Webpack: What is the difference between "all" and "initial" options in optimization.splitChunks.chunks

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm looking for a clear explanation of the difference between these two options in webpack. I've read the description [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) but the difference is not clear. Quoting the description:

> Setting the optimization.splitChunks.chunks option to "all" initial chunks will get affected by it (even the ones not imported dynamically). This way chunks can even be shared between entry points and on-demand loading.

Answer (score 52):

Trying for the simplest explanation. This is the file that will be transpiled and bundled:

```
//app.js
import "my-static-module";

if(some_condition_is_true){
  import ("my-dynamic-module")
}
console.log("My app is running")
```

Now see how different optimization types will treat it.

**async (default):**

Two files will be created.

1. bundle.js (includes app.js + my-static-module)
2. chunk.js (includes my-dynamic-module only)

**initial:**

Three files will be created

1. app.js (includes only app.js)
2. bundle.js (includes only my-static-module)
3. chunk.js (includes only my-dynamic-module)

**all:**

Two files will be created

1. app.js (includes app.js only)
2. bundle.js (includes my-static-module + my-dynamic-module)

"**all**" will have the smallest overall size.

Comment: this is the easiest explanation I've found so far. thank you

Comment: Hi, did you test and confirm the results? I think your answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 12):

`all` means both dynamically imported modules and statically imported modules will be selected for optimization. `initial` means only statically imported modules will be selected for optimization.

Quoting from [Webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunks-chunks):

> possible values are all, async, and initial. Providing all can be particularly powerful because it means that chunks can be shared even between async and non-async chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the example shared by @Sujaan Singh, and consider splitChunks.minSize equal to zero.

These are the files that will be transpiled and bundled:

```
//app.js
import "my-static-module";

import "my-static-vendor-module"

if(some_condition_is_true){
  import ("my-dynamic-module")
}
else{
  import ("my-dynamic-module-1")
}
console.log("My app is running")

//my-dynamic-module.js
import "my-static-module-1";

//my-dynamic-module-1.js
import "my-static-module-1";
```

Now see how different optimization types will treat it.

**async (default):**

Four files will be created.

1. app.js (includes app.js + my-static-module + my-static-vendor-module)
2. 0.app.js (includes my-dynamic-module only)
3. 1.app.js (includes my-dynamic-module-1 only)
4. 2.app.js (includes my-static-module-1 only) : because this module is common to two async chunks

**all:**

Five files will be created

1. app.js (includes only app.js + my-static-module)
2. 0.app.js (includes my-static-vendor-module-1) : minChunks is one by default for vendor modules
3. 1.app.js (includes only my-dynamic-module)
4. 2.app.js (includes my-dynamic-module-1 only)
5. 3.app.js (includes my-static-module-1 only)

**initial:**

Four files will be created

1. app.js (includes only app.js + my-static-module)
2. 0.app.js (includes my-static-vendor-module-1) : minChunks is one by default for vendor modules
3. 1.app.js (includes only my-dynamic-module + my-static-module-1)
4. 2.app.js (includes my-dynamic-module-1 + my-static-module-1)

The default cache groups that SplitChunksPlugin uses:

```
default: {
    idHint: "",
    reuseExistingChunk: true,
    minChunks: 2,
    priority: -20
},
defaultVendors: {
    idHint: "vendors",
    reuseExistingChunk: true,
    test: NODE_MODULES_REGEXP,
    priority: -10
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you test and confirm the results? I think your answer is incorrect.